# SmartWatch 2 app 1.4.51 breaks Low Power Mode

Tags: sony-smartwatch

This issue is an extension of the following:

[v1.4.51 of Sony SmartWatch 2 app breaks Low Power Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229446/v1-4-51-of-sony-smartwatch-2-app-breaks-low-power-mode)

Since updating my Smartwatch 2 app to 1.4.51, the following app fails to initiate a 'Low Power Mode' state:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.zalsky.android.watchremotecontrol

To reproduce the bug, please do the following:

Install Smartmote app.
Go to app's options and switch the Low Power Mode option to 'ON' state.
Play some music (I'm doing so through Google Play Music app).
Open the app from inside the Smartwatch.
Wait a few moments for the screen to dim - At this point, the phone will NOT go into a low power mode state, it will instead go directly the watch face. (It should in fact stay on the album art of the played song, in Low Power Mode.)

I have attempted to fix this issue by factory resetting my Smartwatch, uninstalling and reinstalling the app, clearing Smartwatch 2 app data from my phone and restarting my phone and smartwatch.. Nothing seems to solve the issue and the bug still exists.

Please notice that the app hasn't been updated for a full month and Low Power Mode functioned correctly before Sony recently updated their Smartwatch app.

If there's anything I can do to help squash the bug, let me know.

Many thanks,

Martin

Comment: It is not. It's a app I have purchased from the Playstore.

Comment: It's not really a programming question. You should contact the developer.